# How to remove delay on camera with react-native & tensorflow.js

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

I'm trying to get predict data from tensorflow.js but when get that, camera screen is delayed
how can remove that delay? or have to tranfer tensorflow lite? 
i tested 3 devices(LG v20,iphone 8, Galaxy s10). all devices get same result.

```
'''
const TensorCamera = cameraWithTensors(Camera);

const inputTensorWidth = 224;
const inputTensorHeight = 224;
const AUTORENDER = true;

const App = () => {
  const [hasPermission, setHasPermission] = useState(false);
  const [vector_model, setVector_model] = useState(null);
  let rafId;

  const handleCameraStream = async (images, PaymentRequestUpdateEvent, gl) => {
    const loop = async () => {
      console.log(tf.memory());
      const imgTensor=tf.tidy(()=>{
        let imgTensor = images.next().value;
        imgTensor = tf.cast(imgTensor, "float32");
        imgTensor = imgTensor.expandDims(0);
        return imgTensor;
      })

      const sim =await(await vector_model).predict({ "images": imgTensor },{batchSize:5});

      tf.dispose(imgTensor);
      tf.dispose(sim);
      rafId = requestAnimationFrame(loop);  
      console.log(tf.memory());

    }
    loop();
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const preload = async () => {
      await tf.ready();
      const model = await tf.loadGraphModel("https://tfhub.dev/google/tfjs-model/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_140_224/feature_vector/3/default/1", { fromTFHub: true });
      setVector_model(model);
      const { status } = await Camera.requestPermissionsAsync();
      setHasPermission(status);
    }

    preload();
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    return cancelAnimationFrame(rafId);
  }, [rafId]);
...
```

Comment: Does the delay occur for the first prediction or for all of them ?

Comment: first predicttion. when annotated const sim line, no delayed

Comment: Is there a memory leak, ie tf.memory that keeps growing ?

Comment: nope. just keep same memory in tf.memory()